Is macOS vulnerable to the XZ-vulnerability?
The current state of knowledge seems to suggest that macOS was so far not vulnerable to the recent XZ attack - but I find this hard to establish.
Is macOS really save even if vulnerable liblzma versions are present?
Reason for asking:
Even though the XZ attack was caught before the compromised liblzma version made it into the big Linux distros, it reaches other distributers and was able to spread that way. One of them is homebrew:
For a time homebrew was serving the vulnerable XZ Utils / liblzma versions 5.6.0 and 5.6.1. (I personally observed on my own MacBook pro that I had the 5.6.1 installed via homebrew.)
I figured better safe than sorry. So a quick..
homebrew update & homebrew upgrade

.. solved the issue by downgrading to the last safe version.
But I'd still like to know if my Mac was at risk or not, and how badly we should hound the other Mac users in the company to do the same.

The best write up I've seen can be found here:
https://arstechnica.com/security/2024/04/what-we-know-about-the-xz-utils-backdoor-that-almost-infected-the-world/?utm_brand=arstechnica&utm_campaign=MacAdmins.news&utm_medium=web&utm_social-type=owned&utm_source=MacAdmins.news_310
Key point from linked write up:
“The attack was sneaky in that it only did the final steps of the backdoor if you were building the library on amd64 (intel x86 64-bit) and were building a Debian or a RPM package (instead of using it for a local installation),”"

This is a badly posed question - the question text makes it look like asking about Homebrew and so correctly closed as duplicate. However there is a good question re macOS

I was never interested in the homebrew issue, I presented the solution to that in the original question. Reformulated the question to make it clear that I'm interested in the question is macOS with a compromised liblzma version at risk?

If you don't believe the various sources (including the ArsTechica article linked in the first comment, the quote from said article included in that comment, the Homebrew issues referenced in the linked question, and practically any article explaining how the attack worked) indicating that (as far as currently known) macOS was neither targeted nor at risk, how would an answer need to be written to change this?

To clarify: I agree, the intention makes it not really a duplicate (the wording does, though). But I would like to understand what you would expect from an answer in addition to all the information already available on AD and with some basic research.

Well, at the time of asking this question the answers as to whether macOS is vulnerable or not were not very confident and I never saw a clear post claiming macOS was properly unaffected. If that is now the clear consensus among the security community I would expect to read exactly that in an answer, backed by some links.

I also don't understand why this was migrated, this is clearly a question on XZ, I don't see what this is doing on the apple Q&A...

The original version reads for sure more about Homebrew than about xz as such. And you are right: answers on AD will probably not adhere to the standards the security community would expect. Basically, "The attack was sneaky in that it only did the final steps of the backdoor if you were building the library on amd64 (intel x86 64-bit) and were building a Debian or a RPM package" with a link to the ArsTechnica article would be considered a valid answer.

The current text after your edit with the comment that solved the issue being homebrew commands still makes this question homebrew based and so answered by the other question

For more info see the OpenBSD maintainer of xz's comments https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=171227941117852&w=2

@mmmmmm I'm sorry, I don't see what you are talking about. There is a question about a vulnerability with regards to macOS. There is some background which mentions homebrew. There are zero questions regarding homebrew. I even restated the main question at the bottom again, it has nothing to do with homebrew.

For a question not being about Homebrew, Homebrew is mentioned quite often, which might explain the confusion. Anyway, what kind of research have you done regarding the potential risk on macOS, what did you find, what is still unclear?

@fygsin You say 'I figured better safe than sorry. So a quick..
homebrew update & homebrew upgrade
.. solved the issue by downgrading to the last safe version.' Well that won't fix libxz in macOS if there is an issue. You keep looking as if this is an issue with Homebrew's xz - which is answered elsewhere
